# Problemas no resultado final PYTHON

Tags: python, funções, classes

Sou iniciante em Python e estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora, criando uma classe, dentro dela existem 4 funções, sendo as 4 operações. E no principal apenas o input basico. Meu objetivo neste programa é usar a quantidade mínima de 'If'. Existe uma maneira de fazer isso ou não?
Mas, isso tá dando um erro que não imagino como está acontecendo, pode ser na cara mas vim aqui pedir ajuda:

```
main.py
from calc import *
numero1 = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
sinal = input('Digite a operação: ')
numero2 = int(input('Digite outro numero: '))
retornaValor = 0
retornaValor = Calculadora
print(retornaValor)




calc.py
class Calculadora:

def __init__(self,numero1,numero2):
    self.a = numero1
    self.b = numero2

def soma(self,numero1,numero2):
    soma = self.a + self.b
    print('Resultado: ',soma)

def subtrai(self,numero1,numero2):
    subtrai = self.a - self.b
    print('Resultado: ',subtrai)

def divisao(self,numero1,numero2):
    divisao = self.a / self.b
    print('Resultado: ',divisao)

def multiplica(self,numero1,numero2):
    multiplica = self.a * self.b
    print('Resultado: ',multiplica)

Console: 

Digite um numero: 100
Digite a operação: +
Digite outro numero: 30
''<class 'calc.Calculadora'>'' (????)
```

Comment: Nesse código já não tem nenhum `if`, o que exatamente vc quer reduzir?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: Estava na verdade tentando criar uma calculadora sem o uso intenso de `if` para não ficar tão bagunçado, ou estava ate fazendo sem o uso de `if`, porém acho q isso não e possivel ne...

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer, um exemplo (meio ruim, mas "quase sem if"): https://ideone.com/HPUKYV - na verdade acho que nem precisava de uma classe, mas fazer o que. Aliás, as 2 respostas abaixo não são boas (embora vc ache que sejam, pois até chegou a aceitar uma), pois não faz sentido criar a calculadora passando os valores e depois chamar um método chamando esses mesmos valores (sendo que eles já fazem parte da própria classe) - esse, aliás é um dos problemas de se usar uma classe... Uma delas ainda diz que é "obrigado" a colocar valores default (`n1=1, n2=2`), o que não é verdade...

Comment: Fazendo `Calculadora(n1, n2)` vc tem uma classe que só faz contas com esses 2 números. Se a ideia é calcular com quaisquer números, deveria ser só `Calculadora()` e ela recebe os números nos métodos (como eu fiz no exemplo que coloquei acima). As respostas misturam ambas as soluções e no fim só desensinam (pra que fazer `Calculadora(n1, n2)` se depois vc vai chamar `soma(n1, n2)` (ou seja, guardou os números no construtor, para depois ignorá-los nos métodos)? Mesmo usando `n1=1, n2=1`, vc ainda está guardando valores que serão ignorados depois...

Comment: Acabei de ver aquele seu exemplo, achei bem estranho primeiramente kkkk, no caso então o jeito nesse programa e ao menos usar cada if para operação então? Agradeço a ajuda cara principalmente explicando sobre o uso das classes de um jeito melhor de se entender

Comment: Um `if` para cada operação seria o mais simples, algo como `if operacao == '+': faz a soma, etc`. O `if` é uma das coisas mais básicas em programação, não tem porque querer evitar a todo custo. Se faz sentido, use

Comment: Entendi cara, obrigado pela ajuda...Minha duvida mesmo era saber se existia algum modo reduzir o If mas como você disse acima, geralmente vai sempre fazer sentido pelo jeito kkk...Abs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu testei apenas a parte do código rapidamente, aparentemente você está com um problema de indentação ali. Caso não saiba, tentando explicar de uma forma bem lúdica o que é indentação, ela é um tipo de hierarquia, na qual funções exteriores ficam à esquerda de uma função interior.

As funções interiores são consequências diretas ou só existem a partir de sua função exterior, você também precisa criar um módulo para definir os valores de n1 e n2 no novo objeto.

```
class Calc(object):

# Instanciando a classe Calc
 def __init__(self,n1=1,n2=1): # Quando se trata de valores, temos que colocar um valor padrão apenas pela sintaxe do Python.
# Geralmente esse valor será 1.    
   self.n1 = n1
   self.n2 = n2
      
# Criando um comando para definir os números dos objetos da calsse Calc    
# Logo abaixo pedindo para o que uma soma seja definida e que ela seja mostrada quando o esse comando for executado.
 def setn(self,n1,n2):
    self.n1 = n1
    self.n2 = n2
    print(n1+n2)
    
calculator = Calc() # Criando um objeto calculator da classe Calc()

calculator.setn(n1=float(input()),n2=float(input())) # Pedindo para o objeto calculator executar o módulo setn e definindo os valores dos números.
```

Esse é um exemplo do que você deve fazer com todos os outros itens para que essa parte do código fique funcional.

Comment: Me perdoe a formatação aqui no stack mas a identação que coloquei esta correta, desculpa de vdd, me deu até uma ideia nova. Agradeço muito pela ajuda

Comment: Sou matemática, não programadora, por isso eu provavelmente não criaria uma função de subtração ou de divisão, já que são o inverso da adição e multiplicação. De qualquer forma espero ter ajudado em algo. :3

Comment: Gratidão por ajudar :)